# vs code doesn't show red squiggles

Tags: linux, visual-c++, visual-studio-code

Eg: It doesn't highlight or add red squiggly lines to gibberish("fdfdf")
[image]

I have installed visual studio code on Ubuntu on virtual machine. Whenever I write gibberish code the red squiggly lines that are supposed to appear don't appear. IntelliSense code completion seems to work fine. I tried enabling the error squiggles in folder properties but it still doesn't help.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: upload a screenshot of your problem